# Resizing image to fit frame

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage

A part of my application is working as a tutorial. For that purpose I got JPanels that display a JLabel that has an image as content. Although when the image is larger than what fits the screen it will just cut what doesn't fit. What I need to do is resize the image so that I will fit the space the JLabel is given. Also tried using JScrollPanes but didn't make any difference(although I prefer to resize image).

I tried getting a scaled instance of the image using

```
Image scaledImg = myPicture.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

but it didn't make any difference.

This is the current code :

```
private JLabel getTutorialLabel(int type) {
        String path = "/Images/Tutorial/test" + type + ".png";
        try {
            BufferedImage tutorialPic = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
//            int height = (int) (screenDim.height * 0.9);
//            int width = (int) (screenDim.width * 0.9);
//            Image scaledImg = myPicture.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tutorialPic));
            return picLabel;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tutorial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

> How I get the image to display properly?

Please note that there are other components displayed along with the JLabel(JMenuBar and some buttons on bottom of screen) so I need to image to fill the space JLabel is given.

Comment: You need to use a ComponentListener. Implement componentResized() and scale your image there

Comment: I don't think you get notified when I update my answer, so here's a notification. The new method should work much better.

Comment: Hey, sorry about this, the old method had a critical error in it. I had switched the width and height. I've updated the method, it should be much better now and I've added support for giving negative values for height/width (essentially saying "I don't care for this one"). You could also just call the `resizeImageBy` method directly. It's pretty simple. I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks kentcdodds I have figured this out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: updated the method

You could try [this method](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/SwingHelper.java#L53) in the [Java Helper Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper).

Or, here's the method itself:

```
/**
* This method resizes the given image using Image.SCALE_SMOOTH.
*
* @param image the image to be resized
* @param width the desired width of the new image. Negative values force the only constraint to be height.
* @param height the desired height of the new image. Negative values force the only constraint to be width.
* @param max if true, sets the width and height as maximum heights and widths, if false, they are minimums.
* @return the resized image.
*/
public static Image resizeImage(Image image, int width, int height, boolean max) {
  if (width < 0 && height > 0) {
    return resizeImageBy(image, height, false);
  } else if (width > 0 && height < 0) {
    return resizeImageBy(image, width, true);
  } else if (width < 0 && height < 0) {
    PrinterHelper.printErr("Setting the image size to (width, height) of: ("
            + width + ", " + height + ") effectively means \"do nothing\"... Returning original image");
    return image;
    //alternatively you can use System.err.println("");
    //or you could just ignore this case
  }
  int currentHeight = image.getHeight(null);
  int currentWidth = image.getWidth(null);
  int expectedWidth = (height * currentWidth) / currentHeight;
  //Size will be set to the height
  //unless the expectedWidth is greater than the width and the constraint is maximum
  //or the expectedWidth is less than the width and the constraint is minimum
  int size = height;
  if (max && expectedWidth > width) {
    size = width;
  } else if (!max && expectedWidth < width) {
    size = width;
  }
  return resizeImageBy(image, size, (size == width));
}

/**
* Resizes the given image using Image.SCALE_SMOOTH.
*
* @param image the image to be resized
* @param size the size to resize the width/height by (see setWidth)
* @param setWidth whether the size applies to the height or to the width
* @return the resized image
*/
public static Image resizeImageBy(Image image, int size, boolean setWidth) {
  if (setWidth) {
    return image.getScaledInstance(size, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
  } else {
    return image.getScaledInstance(-1, size, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
  }
}
```

Comment: Java Help Library.. *"feel free to fork and use it!"*  Uh, no thanks.  Not after looking at that little classic. 1) Use `ImageIO` rather than an `ImageIcon` to load an `Image`.  Then you don't need a `MediaTracker` (which is missing from the code, in any case). 2) See [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) for why *not* to rely on that simple, convenience method. 3) Don't accept a `String` when the method expect an `Image`!  That method would be unusable for a) an image generated in memory b) an image on ..

Comment: ..the local file-system c) an image at an URL. 4) Then we finish with this classic.. `Image image1 = new ImageIcon(newimg).getImage();` is equivalent to `Image image1 = newimg;`

Comment: Hah, well, this isn't a SO conversation, so I'll just say thanks for the tips and if you think it could be improved you can "feel free to fork it" to improve it ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Just in case you're interested, I've updated the method. I read that article you pointed to, and asked a question on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11214 and decided that using Image.getScaledInstance() would be the best way to go for this kind of a method. (We all have our opinions on the best way to do things). This may not be the best way to do this still, but it works every time for me. If you see anything else in the Java Helper you think could/should be changed, feel free to create a new issue and I'll get to it (like this one) :)