# Show a big image in a smaller label Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have this Java Swing code :

```
ImageIcon img;
img = new ImageIcon("./pictures/icon2.jpg");
label1.setIcon(img);
```

I change the size of the label but I need a very big label to show a big image. Cause I need to show more images with different sizes in the same label I need to show the full image in a smaller than image size label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java resize an image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28701599/418556) or [Resizing image to fit frame](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10306335/418556) or [Resizing image to fit in JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22679717/418556) or..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine now.

```
File file = new File("./pictures/icon2.jpg");
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(file);
Image scaled = bimg.getScaledInstance(500, 500, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaled);
photo_result.setIcon(icon);
```